# Using Office 365 login as identity provider for my web app

Tags: ms-office, preview

I want my users to be able to connect with same email/pass combination in reporting system for my company as they use for Office 365 and outlook.

Reporting system is in my server, simple PHP engine and i don't want to mess with double login info for every user and for every system. So far i couldn't find any solution how to use O365's login/session. So i wonder if it is possible at all and how?

Comment: http://macfoo.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/how-to-log-into-office365-or-sharepoint-online-using-php/ - Seen this?

Comment: no, im gona see if i can sync their pass change too?...

Comment: The code in the article seems to log in directly to Office 365, so no need to sync users at all.

Comment: i wish also to be able if i create user in my web app to be able to create an o365 account and outlook account with my domain immediately. without having to touch o365 administration... i believe this is enough.. i should use API for this... thank you..i hope it still works with curl...

Comment: That I do not now exactly how, but you could look into the O365-API-stuff here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn467914(v=office.15).aspx . I'm guessing it should be possible somehow, but it might not be exposed as web services by default (which would then require you to make an ASP.NET app to handle the actual signup, then calling that with your PHP app).

Comment: ah lovely M$ "why simple when it can be complicated"

Comment: I'm saying it *might* not be.

Comment: :D but it's often like that :D we all know it